# Programa nao le primeiro scanf e pula o segundo scanf do script

Tags: c

Tento criar um algoritmo, porém quando vou ler o conteúdo do primeiro scanf, ele só imprime a primeira letra do nome. O segundo scanf que deveria ler um número é ignorado e automaticamente imprime o resultado do primeiro if

```
#include <stdio.h>

//Compiler version gcc  6.3.0

int main()
{
  int tentativas = 0;
  int nivel;
  int numeroDaSorte = rand() % 100;
  char nome;


  printf("Bem vindo ao jogo de adivinhacao\n");
  printf("\nQual o seu nome?\n");
  scanf("%c", &nome);
  printf("\n\nSeja Bem Vindo %c", nome);
  printf("\n Qual nivel de dificuldade vc deseja?");
  printf("\n1 - facil");
  printf("\n2 - medio");
  printf("\n3 - dificil");
  scanf("%d", &tentativas);

  if(tentativas = 1)
  {

     printf("\n Nivel facil, vc tem 15 tentativas ");
     nivel = 15;
     }
      else
      if(tentativas = 2) {
        printf("\n Nivel medio, vc tem 10 tentativas");
        nivel = 10;
        }
        else {
          printf("\n nivel dificil, vc tem 5 tentativas");
          nivel = 5;
        }

  }
```

Comment: está certo, `char nome` é uma variável `char`, ou seja, armazena 1 caractere. Para armazenar um nome precisa ser um array

Comment: Aqui: ` if(tentativas = 1)`você não está comparando a variável tentativas com 1, está atribuindo 1 à variável tentativas. Para comparar utilize o operador `==`: ` if (tentativas == 1)`. Idem demais `if`. Quanto ao nome declare `char nome[3];`e utilize o formato `%s` no scanf: `scanf("%s", nome);` (sem &).

Comment: Erro de digitação. Declare `char nome[50];` ou o tamanho que julgar conveniente.

Answer (score 0):

Tu precisa estudar um pouco mais sobre string, assim como disseram nas outras respostas. Tu declarou a variável nome como char , um char é apenas um caractere , ou seja, apenas a primeira letra do nome que tu digitou. Importe a bibioteca string.h, você também vai precisar mudar a declaração da variável nome. Fazendo isso , no printf tu vai chamar ela por %s (string) ao invés de %c (char) .